# Join text to several multi-level lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list, addition

Using Python, I have a bunch of lists I want to join some text to. These lists have multi-level entries (or whatever term it is used to describe it), like this:

```
list1:
   (['abc'],
    ['def', 'ghi'])
list2:
   (['123'],
    ['456', '789'])
```

I would like to join the string 'X' to each element of both lists:

```
list1:
   (['Xabc'],
    ['Xdef', 'Xghi'])
list2:
   (['X123'],
    ['X456', 'X789'])
```

I just **can't do it neatly**. I did some 'for loops' but it seems incredibly poor, and not reproducible, considering I have several lists:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list1):
    for index2, item2 in enumerate(item):
        list1[index][index2] = "X" + item2

for index, item in enumerate(list2):
    for index2, item2 in enumerate(item):
        list2[index][index2] = "X" + item2
```

I know this should be a one liner. I found some answers for single simple lists but the ones I have contain multi-level (multi-elements?) and there is more than one list:

```
list = ["X" + string for string in list]
```

I just can't adapt this. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that although many problems can be achieved with a one-liner, Readability Counts.

Comment: @Blake using a data analytics library to prepend something to strings is massively overkill here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested to learn about slice assignment, if you were concerned about all the indexes you were creating with enumeration and what not.

```
for b in list1 :
    b[:]= ["X"+a for a in b]
```

Though technically this doesn't do assignment in place (it creates a list for the list comprehension) it will effectively update list1 directly, and doesn't require you to then assign list1 = [list comprehension]

If you want to actually supply individual parameters you would use star to pack the variables into a list.

```
def update_lists(prepend_text, *lists) :
    for list in lists :
        update_list(prepend_text, list)

def update_list(prepend_text, list) :
    for b in list :
        b[:]= [prepend_text+a for a in b] 
update_lists("X", list1,list2)
```

Alternatively you can define the function like this:

```
def update_lists(prepend_text, lists) :
    for list in lists :
        update_list(prepend_text, list)
```

and then call the function as

```
update_lists("X", [list1,list2])
```

or perhaps better if you create the list of lists dynamically

```
lists = []
lists.append(list1)
lists.append(list2)
update_lists("X", lists)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I did it like this:
for c in (list1, list2):
    for b in c:
        b[:]= ["X" + a for a in b]

Comment: Added some stuff on how to use it in a function for multiple lists.

Answer (score 2):

You need a nested list comprehension to preserve the structure in the resulting list:

```
list1 = [['abc'], ['def', 'ghi']]

[[f'X{j}' for j in i] for i in list1]
# [['X{}'.format(j) for j in i] for i in list1] # for python 3.6 <
[['Xabc'], ['Xdef', 'Xghi']]
```

---

For *multiple lists* you could define the following generator function:

```
def add_text(text, *lists): 
    for l in lists:
        yield [[text + '{}'.format(j) for j in i] for i in l] 

l1, l2 = list(add_text('X', list1, list2))

print(l1)
# [['Xabc'], ['Xdef', 'Xghi']]

print(l2)
# [['XX123'], ['XX456', 'XX789']]
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of having several lists but it's a massive simplification! Thank you!

Comment: So you could just define a function and use it on all lists? @spcvalente

Comment: Yes. I could. If I knew, sorry about that, heheh. I can define simple functions but this one has a bit more iteration and I can't do it, and I don't know how can I input the text bit on the formula: def add_text(text, lists):
    for element in lists:
        element = [[text + '{}'.format(j) for j in i] for i in element] # ???
Could you please enlighten me? Thanks again yatu.

Comment: It certainly does. Somehow it doesn't output the result but I'm very happy with your answer as I learned a lot. Thanks you again!

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach for nested lists :

```
list1=[['abc'], [ ['def', 'ghi'],'jlk']]


def apply(f,nested) :
    if isinstance(nested,str): return f(nested)
    return [ apply(f,x) for x in nested ]

apply(lambda s : "X"+s , list1 )
Out : [['Xabc'], [['Xdef', 'Xghi'], 'Xjlk']]
```